# PFUser array of pointers column, fetch objects for currentUser

Tags: arrays, pointers, parse-platform

My PFUser subclass contains a column which is an array of pointers. When showing the [PFUser currentUser] profile page, the array objects are not included and calling

```
[[PFUser currentUser fetchIfNeededInBackground]
```

won't fetch the pointer objects either.

If the column was a single pointer, I could call

```
[currentUser[@"pointerColumn"] fetchIfNeedInBackground]
```

but the method's argument is a PFObject and not an Array of Pointers.

I can call fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock for every object in the array, but that makes many requests for a single column in the PFUser class.

```
for (PFObject * obj in currentUserArrayOfPointers) {
  [obj fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){
    [self.tableView reloadData];
  }];
}
```

Is there a better way to fetch [PFUser currentUser]'s array of pointers column?

(And keep the behavior of "fetchIfNeeded", which avoids making a new query each time if the object was already fetched.)

Comment: When you say an array of pointers, do you mean an array of object ID's?

Comment: An array of pointer looks like:
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"myClassName","objectId":"7sdf8sdf9j"}, {"__type":"Pointer","className":"myClassName","objectId":"7fge8agfd9"}]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get all the objectIds in your currentUserArrayOfPointers and then do a parse query with this parameter:

```
NSMutableArray *userObjectIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (PFObject * obj in currentUserArrayOfPointers) {
    [userObjectIds add:object.objectId];
}

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SomeClass"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:userObjectIds];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error {
    ...
}];
```

This way you'll be able to get all the users with one query.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this resolves the problem of multiple queries indeed. There is an issue though.
The arrayOfPointers is a column in the PFUser class. I need to display this information when the currentUser opens his Profile Page. With this method, if I'm not wrong, a new request will be made each time the currentUser opens the profile page? If the user has already opened his profile page once, is there a way to avoid the request if the objects have already been fetched once?